# Does wp7 have sdk to read phone data transfer

Tags: windows-phone-7

I hope to get the data transfer info.
I have done the same thing on iPhone but not sure if wp7 sdk has the same function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at the moment, there is no data transfer API. I assume you mean total data usage from other apps and the phone in general. You could monitor your own app by manually making web requests and storing the bytes used but there's no way to monitor how much is being used by other apps.